# Find Average of Last 10 Numerical Values in a Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to find a way to get the average for the last 10 numerical values in column G. I am struggling a bit here as there are sporadic blanks in the column (not every row has a number in column G) and there are non-numerical values containing sub-averages combined with text in the column as well. Any help here would be appreciated.
Here is some sample data:

[image: Example Data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365, you can use:

```
=LET(x,FILTER(G:G,ISNUMBER(G:G)),y,ROWS(x),AVERAGE(INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(10,,y-9,1))))
```

With earlier versions, try:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(14,6,1/ISNUMBER(G:G)*ROW(G:G),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,10)))))
```

*This latter is an array formula. Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to enter/confirm it as an **array formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.*

Comment: With the latest set of data, the Office 365 equation comes out perfectly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(G:G,LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(G:G),ROW(G:G)),10)):G22)
```

G22 is a kludge.  It is last entry in Table.  You should be able to figure out how to get index.

Comment: Nice and simple. I think `G22` can be any row greater than the end of the column.  Even, for example: `G1000000`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yeah, I like the aspect of Excel allowing a function to be developed on the fly.  Mine was fairly easy for me, but yours was probably easier since I saw it being written.  Looking forward to dissecting it when I get a chance.  Still learning Excel.